# How to get data data in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run this,

```
Module.find(function(err,Module){
  console.log(Module);
});
```

It returns data like

```
{ _id: 57f769b130bbaf129c586eb5, Name: 'Sydney', Status: true },
{ _id: 57f76e19f30d3c1ca02d002b, Name: 'zamora', Status: true },
```

How to get the data of `Name` and `Status`? and store it in a variable
    like in java.

```
String name = db.getString("Name");
```

Comment: In which variable you want to save it? don't forget that node.js is run in async nature so you need to take care about that.Otherwise you will get some weird scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for loop:

```
var Name=[];
var Status=[]; 

for(i=0;i<Module.length;i++) {
     console.log(Module[i].Name);
     console.log(Module[i].Status);
     Name[i] = Module[i].Name;
     Status[i]= Module[i].Status;
}
```

in this way, you can get data of Name and Status and store it.

Comment: In this case user always get last element in array. I think you need to define it above loop.